# HoloLens2: Get 403 when using "api/taskmanager/process" to kill a process

Tags: uwp, httpclient, hololens

Goal:
Want to kill a specific HoloLens2 process (following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core))

Here is what I did on my Windows 10 machine:

(0) Connect my HoloLens2 to my Windows machine, developer enabled, with username and password,

(1) Open HoloLens2 Device portal https://ipaddress/#Home, using the username and password, .

(2) Execute C# code , HttpClient Get "api/resourcemanager/processes" to get all processes using basic security,

All above steps finished successfully.

(3) Select a specific HoloLens2 process (created by me and started by me) using basic security,
call HttpClient Delete "api/taskmanager/process?pid=XXXX",

This step returns 403

Need help to troubleshoot this, where can I find a sample code.

Thanks,

Expect the HoloLens process to be killed as spec'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Device portal API reference - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/device-portal-api-reference#task-manager). Currently, HoloLens 2 Device Portal does not support this API, you can try **/API/Taskmanager/App (Delete)**.